# Splitting a string of two lines in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In a function, I'm getting a string like

```
'SHOWONLY_Clearance/Closeout
(21)'
```

I want to split this string using '_'. Here is my code

```
function showResult(resStr)
{
    var substr = resStr.split('_');
    alert(substr[0]);
    alert(substr[1]);
}
```

Its not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't look like 2 lines.  What makes you sure that's the case?

Comment: Can we have a [demo, please](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Is `resArr` definitely a string? With a name like that it sounds like an array.

Comment: Removed JQuery tag and from the title, as this is base Javascript.

Comment: @David Thomas: here you go! It works perfectly for me http://jsfiddle.net/dZyk5/

Comment: @nico: yeah, but I was more curious as to what the OP was doing that made it not-work. =)

Comment: Its not an array. Here Its not displayed in two lines but when I'm giving `alert(resStr)`, its being displayed in two lines.

Comment: @user1302900: in any case, the newline is not the problem, see http://jsfiddle.net/dZyk5/1/

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful description. What do expect? What do you get instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine, check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/yVV3s/)

Comment: maybe there's an error in your resStr that you are passing to the function.

Comment: If '(21)' is in next line, how to make it work?

Comment: JavaScript recognizes string in a single line, if you want it to continue to the next line you must add a `\` at the end of first line or use \n as the new line feed. [http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/yVV3s/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/yVV3s/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you can't see the character causing the new line, it might be a newline, carriage return or form feed. Try the following:

```
function showResult(resStr) {
    var re = /[\u000a\u000c\u000d]/g;
    var parts = resStr.replace(re, '').split('_');
    alert(substr[0] + '\n' + substr[1]);
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to remove all whitespace, just things that cause new lines.